# Удаление нулей с начала строки

Tags: php, строки

Доброго времени! есть переменная с числом которое может начинаться с нулей (или не может)

```
$y = 0000001;
```

попробовал удалять с помощью ltrim() вот так:

```
 ltrim($y,'0'); //выдает при $y= 000001 - 1
```

а дальше какая то дич вобще

```
 ltrim($y,'0'); //выдает при $y= 000000011 - 9 (????wtf)
```

видимо там какой то синтаксис определнный указать надо? подскажите пожалуйста, или вобще другой способ юзать?

Comment: будь она строка или не строка, вот такое  `echo $y+0;` выведет 1

Comment: Я чего-то не понял?.. Почему не сделать так: `(int) <value>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Литералы чисел, начинающиеся с нуля - восьмеричное представление. Соответственно если вы выполните просто `print 000000011;` получите 9. А вот если вы сделаете так:

```
$y = '000000011';
print ltrim($y,'0');
```

То все будет как вы и ожидаете

Comment: аа воно как! а как лучше числовую переменную в строку преобразовать?? у меня она в начале числовая по идее? так пойдет? $y = (string)$y;

Comment: У числовой переменной при хранении не может быть нулей слева (ну или наоборот они там есть всегда, смотря как посмотреть). Появление или не появление нулей слева происходит при преобразовании в строку. Как у вас проявилась даная проблема?

Comment: Да вы правы) я просто перестраховаться решил на всякий раз)

Comment: @dantelol это к вопросу о том, что перестраховка на пустом месте отнимает кучу времени у кучи людей

Answer (score 0):

```
$y = '000000011';
echo '$y(int)='.(int)$y;
```

Comment: а ведь работает и без всяких ltrim :) http://ideone.com/1CA0NV